# encrypt passwords with python in same format as postfix mysql

Tags: python, mysql, postfix-mta

I am working on a Postfix Virtual Mail Server. I have directions on how to add users with MySQL. I am hoping to find a Python equivalent of what is suggested in MySQL. This is because I want users to be sending me an encrypted (hashed) password they have generated using Python.

Currently to add users it suggests this:

```
INSERT INTO 'servermail`.`virtual_users`
(`id`, `domain_id`, `password` , `email`)
VALUES
('1', '1', ENCRYPT('firstpassword', CONCAT('$6$', SUBSTRING(SHA(RAND()), -16))), 'email1@example.com'),
('2', '1', ENCRYPT('secondpassword', CONCAT('$6$', SUBSTRING(SHA(RAND()), -16))), 'email2@example.com');
```

I want a Python equivalent of the ENCRYPT function in MySQL that outputs an encrypted password.

```
ENCRYPT('firstpassword', CONCAT('$6$', SUBSTRING(SHA(RAND()), -16))
```

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/158400/etc-shadow-how-to-generate-6-s-encrypted-password

Comment: Thanks, but what is the salt in what I've posted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve that by simply running:

```
import crypt

password = "test_pass"
encrypted_password = crypt.crypt(password, crypt.mksalt(crypt.METHOD_SHA512))
```

Note that if your MySQL uses base64 encoding, you also need to encode it after:

```
import base64

base64_encoded_password = base64.b64encode(str.encode(encrypted_password))
```

SQL Example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb/25257/0

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers give exactly what the (MySQL) expression specified.
What worked for me was to exactly simulate the SQL:

```
import crypt
import hashlib
import random

sha1 = hashlib.sha1()
sha1.update(str(random.random))
password = crypt.crypt(plaintext_password, "$6$" + sha1.hexdigest()[-16:])
```